# What would be the pay for a child deck-hand in the 1600's?

Tags: 17th-century, ships, new-world

There is this short story I am writing, and I want to be somewhat historically accurate in the details.

In the story, there is a young orphan boy who is serving as a deck-hand on a cargo ship from France to the New World (Quebec).  The year would be 1635.

My question is, how much would he have gotten paid for serving as deckhand on the overseas voyage?

If, being a child, he doesn't get paid, and the Mate wanted to give him a little gift of our modern $30, how much would he give him?  (I'm [looking at this page](https://freepages.rootsweb.com/~unclefred/genealogy/MONETARY.htm)) Would it be in *sols*, maybe?

Comment: Hello & Welcome! They wouldn't be going from England to Quebec in 1635 as Quebec would have been French. English settlements would have been in St John's and perhaps around the Hudson Bay.

Comment: He was an orphan.  I haven't actually said where the ship came from, but the boy's name is Eustace; maybe he was in Normandy?  But you are right - it wouldn't have been an English ship...  Thanks for pointing that out.  I guess maybe he could be a French kid.  In my story I've only given him a name, not a place of origin, so I have some unknowns to work with.

Comment: I'll update my question.

Comment: Likely zero. He'd be fed and that's it.

Comment: @Spencer: More likely: fed, clothed, housed, and trained in one or more valuable trades in addition to being an able-bodied seaman: carpentry, gunnery, cooking, sail-making/repair, galley-work, perhaps evven navigation if mathematically inclied preparing him for service in His Majesty's Navy as a*midshipman*..

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Wouldn't midshipman be on a path to Lieutenant? The *Ancien Regime* always seemed to have its naval officers as nobles, but I'm not too familiar with their practice.

Comment: More likely to be a ship's boy than a midshipman. Midshipman's billets are limited, and more likely to be filled by children of privilege. And as Mr. Geerkens says, why would anyone pay a child?  Children are trained, not paid.

Comment: @gktscrk: Can't speak for the *Ancien Regime's* practice - but Royal Navy ships were always short of hands (at least in times of war - which was frequent) - that's the excuse if not the cause of the *War of 1812-15*.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Perhaps I was a little too terse, but that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Fair enough. The OP changed from the RN to France. Also, I don't think it needs to be a military ship (so a trading one could also work).

Comment: The French had their equivalent to the midshipman, the [*Gardes de la Marine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gardes_de_la_Marine). But these were not orphaned deck hands.

Comment: Reading this page, I made it so that the Mate gives him 7 Sols;  the reference says it cost 6 sols to feed a man for one day in 1650.  https://freepages.rootsweb.com/~unclefred/genealogy/MONETARY.htm

Comment: Here's a research hint, the English Navy's pay rates were set in 1653.

Comment: I've found that landsman made 18s per month. A cabin boy made less than that, but his pay actually went to the Captain he served and was only given his pay by the good graces of his Captain, probably a few shillings on making land. Oh, and any sailor in an actual position, such as midshipman, or even a landsman, would not have been considered a child, but a young man.